# How to use reduce in a Promise.all instead of map

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

How can I use reduce in the place of map when using Promise.all? My attempt results in an error `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: #<Promise> is not iterable at Function.all (<anonymous>)`

Eventually I would like to conditionally add innerResult to memo but I need to use reduce first.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

const eq = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];

// block to replace
var biggerEq = _.map(eq, async (e) => {
  const innerResult = await wait(e.id);
  return innerResult;
})

// attempt at replacing above block
// var biggerEq = _.reduce(eq, async (memo, e) => {
//   const innerResult = await wait(e.id);
//   memo.push(innerResult)
//   return memo;
// }, []);

Promise.all(biggerEq).then((result) => {
  console.log(result) // outputs [ 2, 4, 6 ]
})


function wait (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(id  * 2);
    }, 1000);
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a reason for using lodash instead of the `Array.prototype` methods?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. `Array.map` and `Array.reduce` have two completely different use cases. It's unclear why you are trying to iterate on an array of promises. Are you trying to itterate on the results that come back tom Promise.all?

Comment: "*How can I use reduce in the place of map*" - why? What is your actual goal? What do you mean by "*Eventually I would like to conditionally add innerResult to memo*"?

Comment: The reason I want to use reduce instead of map is because sometimes the result from wait is undesirable in biggerEq. I could loop biggerEq again to remove unwanted results, but I thought if it would be better if I just didn't add them in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace it with `reduce`, it's possible, but the logic will be a bit convoluted. Make the accumulator a Promise that resolves to an array that you can `push` to, then return it so the next iteration can use it (as a Promise):

```js
const eq = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];

function wait (id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(id  * 2);
    }, 1000);
  })
}

const biggerEq = _.reduce(eq, async (arrProm, obj) => {
  const [arr, innerResult] = await Promise.all([arrProm, wait(obj.id)]);
  arr.push(innerResult);
  return arr;
}, Promise.resolve([]));

biggerEq.then((arr) => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

(but `.map` is really more appropriate when you want to transform one array into another)

Answer (score 1):

I think CertainPerformance over-complicated it. You can use reduce like this with Promise.all:

```
const eq = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}];

function wait(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(id  * 2);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const biggerEq = _.reduce(eq, (arr, obj) => {
  const p = wait(obj.id);
  arr.push(p);
  return arr;
}, []);

Promise.all(biggerEq).then((arr) => {
  console.log(arr);
});
```

Note that the problem was with using `await` inside the reduce. That meant that you were pushing the results of the promises into the array, not getting an array of promises. Using that method, you *already have your results* in the array, so there's no need for `Promise.all`, but there's the big disadvantage that the promises are resolved consecutively. If that's actually what you want, you can have:

```
const results = _.reduce(eq, async (arr, obj) => {
  const p = await wait(obj.id);
  arr.push(p);
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Well using `reduce` is still over-complicated, the same thing could (and should) be done with `map`. Why the OP was trying to use reduce we don't know. Maybe he attempted to do a sequential asynchronous iteration?

Comment: True enough @Bergi. I'll edit for that possibility.